# How to update a slider max when a checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery

I've been working on this all morning.  I've looked at various answers here but cannot seem to get any of them to work.

Here is my HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="200" id="200Box" value="1" onClick="open200()">

 <input id="destinationSpecialistSlider" name="destinationSpecialistSlider" class="no-border w-75" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="1500" step="100" style="height: 0.5em" oninput="destinationSpecialistSlider_disp.value = destinationSpecialistSlider.value">
           <div>
           <p>$<output  id="destinationSpecialistSlider_disp" class="m-0" style="height: 1.5em">0</output></p></b>
           </div>
```

And my jQuery:

```
function open200(){

  if($(document.getElementById('200Box')).is(":checked"))  

                alert("yes"),

                    $("#destinationSpecialistSlider").slider('option',{min: 0, max: 7500});

                else

                alert("no");}
```

The alerts are working, but I cannot seem to get the max option on the slider to change.

I'm sure this is something stupid, but I've been staring at it so long that I can't seem to see it.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Important - remove onClick event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#200Box').change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
           $("#destinationSpecialistSlider").attr('max', 7500).val(0);

        }else
        {
           $("#destinationSpecialistSlider").attr('max', 1500).val(0);
        }

    });
});
```